# How to disable AnyDesk autostart in Ubuntu?

Tags: services, anydesk

AnyDesk runs in Ubuntu startup and I couldn't find any setting in order to disable it in its settings. How can I disable AnyDesk autostart?

Comment: Actually this issue still happens in all Ubuntu versions 22 and 23 (tested in 23.04)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I've found the following approach to disable the AnyDesk service. In this way, you can run it manually.

```
systemctl disable anydesk.service
```

You can also check its service status:

```
systemctl status anydesk
```

nb: you might want to stop it first (or after) if it is running:

```
service anydesk stop
```

Comment: successfully tested also on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This also used to work in Fedora 36, but in 37 it doesn't anymore. The service can be disabled, and stays disabled, but the system tray icon keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

go to the .anydesk/ path(for example: mine is /home/pyruz/.anydesk), find autostart.conf and delete it.
just this.

anydesk version: 6.1.1 , ubuntu version: 22.04 LTS

Comment: **autostart.conf** Not found in 6.2.1

Comment: As @HosseinKurd mentioned, the file doesn't exist in recent versions. Also, `grep -rinw 'autos' /home/user/.anydesk` returns nothing.